# Implications on my server's bandwidth usage when embedding files such as videos or images from YouTube or Google Drive

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-drive-api, youtube-api, bandwidth

I'm trying to reduce my server's AWS bandwidth usage costs. My web application will have a lot of images and videos of my users and I would like to know if embedding these files from YouTube or Google Drive would reduce these costs. Would you pay for the use of bandwidth or not?

Comment: Use like storage service like S3 rather than storing on an EC2 instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store your videos on youtube, not in your aws account - then the user's browser downloads it directly from youtube - avoiding bandwidth charges for you.

Comment: Thanks!

Would the same thing happen if i uploaded a video or any other file to google drive and it will use the api?

Comment: If the video or file is pulled from the browser, not from a backend server you run, it should also offload the bandwidth from your account - i.e. if the user's browser is talking to the 3rd party service directly, that is not bandwidth charged to you normally.